# adb command select device, which is not connected to workstation

Tags: android, shell, android-studio, adb, android-debug

I have a device connected to a worksation, lets says it serial number to be "abcdefgh", whenever I run any adb command, it throws an o/p "adb: unable to connect for root: device 'mnopqrst' not found", the device wih serial number 'mnopqrst' is not connected to worksation. So for any command to run on device, I have to run "adb -s abcdefgh .....". Is  there any way this issue can be resolved without uninstalling the drivers ?

Comment: what's the output of `adb devices` ?

Comment: It shows : "abcdefgh    device"